# In the definition of k-partite graph, is it necessary that k should be minimum?

Tags: graph-theory

It is well known that a graph is said to be $k$-partite if its vertex set can be partitioned in to k non empty sets such that no two vertices in the same set are adjacent.

My question is whether such a '$k$' must be minimum ? ; but the definition doesn't have such a condition explicitly.

A reason for this question is as follows: If we do not assume this condition, then every graph on $k $ vertices is $k$-partite, with all the singleton subsets of its vertex set as the partitions. Likewise, the totally disconnected graph on $k$ vertices ( i.e the graph on $k$ vertices having no edges) can be viewed as a r- partite graph for each  $1 \leq r \leq k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is less restrictive the larger $k$ gets, so less interesting, but it is true.  Given a bipartite graph, you can arbitrarily split one of the parts in two and make a $3-$partite graph.  If you prove a theorem about $3-$partite graphs it will apply to bipartite graphs (at least those with at least $3$ vertices).

Comment: In order to prove a graph to be $k$-partite, is it enough to find a partition of the vertex set having k subsets satisfying the condition that no two vertices in the same sets are adjacent ?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition.  I then suggested how, if you have a $k-$ partite graph you could prove it $m-$ partite for any $m \gt k$ until you run out of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not, for example, every bipartite graph is also $5$-partite.

Comment: @ Jorge: But a bipartite graph is 2-partite.

Comment: exactly, if it is $k$-partiite it is also $s-$partite for all $s>k$.